# MySQL Pivot data into Year Months

Tags: php, mysql, pivot

I have two tables student and class fees, i want to get report to view that students paid their fees or not.

i tried this mysql query and this is i exactly wanted but there is an issue with month and years also im getting empty columns.

this is the query i tried

```
    SELECT
        student.stu_name,
        SUM(IF(MONTH(fees.date) = 1, fees.amt, 0)) AS Jan,
        SUM(IF(MONTH(fees.date) = 2, fees.amt, 0)) AS Feb,
        SUM(IF(MONTH(fees.date) = 3, fees.amt, 0)) AS Mar,
        SUM(IF(MONTH(fees.date) = 4, fees.amt, 0)) AS Apr,
        SUM(IF(MONTH(fees.date) = 5, fees.amt, 0)) AS May,
        SUM(IF(MONTH(fees.date) = 6, fees.amt, 0)) AS Jun,
        SUM(IF(MONTH(fees.date) = 7, fees.amt, 0)) AS Jul,
        SUM(IF(MONTH(fees.date) = 8, fees.amt, 0)) AS Aug,
        SUM(IF(MONTH(fees.date) = 9, fees.amt, 0)) AS Sep,
        SUM(IF(MONTH(fees.date) = 10, fees.amt, 0)) AS Oct,
        SUM(IF(MONTH(fees.date) = 11, fees.amt, 0)) AS Nov,
        SUM(IF(MONTH(fees.date) = 12, fees.amt, 0)) AS Dece,
        SUM(fees.amt) AS Total,
        (28000-(SUM(fees.amt))) AS Balance
    FROM
        `fees`
    INNER JOIN student ON fees.stu_id = student.id
    GROUP BY student.stu_id
```

[This is the result i'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpRbm.png)

if i add data in two years there will be a problem.

[I want to get table like this (orders by month years)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3oykX.png)

i have been working on it for weeks but i couldnt find any solution. i appreciate if you can help me for this.

Comment: I just don't understand why you would do this when you have php available.

Comment: i dont understand how to do this using php. but i found tutorial [link](http://onlybluefeet.com/2015/01/18/how-to-rotate-rows-into-columns-in-mysql/) i couldnt convert into php. can you help me please? im stucked here. i'm sorry if this is not hard as i think because i self studied all the things from internet.

Comment: The two results seem to have nothing to do with each other. This makes it difficult to help further. See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is probably too late for this answer, but I would recomend a third table feedsTotals to set the total of feeds for each year. Like this:

```
create table feesTotals (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  year INT,
  total DECIMAL(13,2),
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO feesTotals(year,total) 
VALUES (2018, 28000.00) , (2019, 29000.00);
```

Than you can do the query you want like this:

```
SELECT
        student.stu_name,
        feesTotals.year,
        SUM(IF(MONTH(fees.date) = 1, fees.amt, 0)) AS Jan,
        SUM(IF(MONTH(fees.date) = 2, fees.amt, 0)) AS Feb,
        SUM(IF(MONTH(fees.date) = 3, fees.amt, 0)) AS Mar,
        SUM(IF(MONTH(fees.date) = 4, fees.amt, 0)) AS Apr,
        SUM(IF(MONTH(fees.date) = 5, fees.amt, 0)) AS May,
        SUM(IF(MONTH(fees.date) = 6, fees.amt, 0)) AS Jun,
        SUM(IF(MONTH(fees.date) = 7, fees.amt, 0)) AS Jul,
        SUM(IF(MONTH(fees.date) = 8, fees.amt, 0)) AS Aug,
        SUM(IF(MONTH(fees.date) = 9, fees.amt, 0)) AS Sep,
        SUM(IF(MONTH(fees.date) = 10, fees.amt, 0)) AS Oct,
        SUM(IF(MONTH(fees.date) = 11, fees.amt, 0)) AS Nov,
        SUM(IF(MONTH(fees.date) = 12, fees.amt, 0)) AS Dece,
        feesTotals.total AS Total,
        (feesTotals.total-(SUM(IFNULL(fees.amt,0)))) AS Balance
FROM student CROSS JOIN feesTotals 
LEFT JOIN fees ON fees.stu_id = student.id AND YEAR(fees.date) = feesTotals.year
GROUP BY student.stu_name, feesTotals.year, feesTotals.total
```

See sample on DB Fiddle [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2cjRBfRZUztt7pSgHmgCWt/0)